# Cannot find default form templates after upgrading django from 3.x to 4.x

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I just upgraded django from 3.x to 4.x.
I am getting error for template not found:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/
django/forms/errors/list/default.html
```

The template is in this location:

```
./lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html
```

Django is trying to look in those locations:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: ./project/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./project/android/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./project/webapp/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2_provider/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./lib/python3.8/site-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ./lib/python3.8/site-packages/ajax_select/templates/django/forms/errors/list/default.html (Source does not exist)
```

So obviously, django is not even looking into it's own django.forms directory and I cannot figure out why. Is there some new settings on 4.x, that I am missing?

Edit:
It is caused in all places, where there's a form and `form.non_field_errors` is called, because returned `ErrorList` class is using this template.

Comment: If it's a library issue have you tried resetting your environment?

Comment: @K.H. try setting the path to the templates in the settings.py file: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, './lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/errors/list')],
'APP_DIRS': True,

Comment: @OctaviodelSer I tried reverting all the libraries to original version. In fact reverting django to 3.2.15 itself helps. Definitely don't wanna use absolute path to reference django templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out why these templates aren't found. If 'django.forms' isn't in the INSTALLED_APPS, the template directory isn't found. I've not checked the Django docs, but perhaps this is a side-effect of a tightening of the template search behaviour. The default setup has `APP_DIRS: True`, but i'm guessing you didn't have that in your TEMPLATES dict like me - as the default setup finds the template ok (ie if viewing the admin)

Here's what worked for me:

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.humanize",
    "django.forms",
]
```

NB I use a cookie cutter based template which separates out Django apps from third party and project apps.

As pointed out by K.H. this is mentioned in the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/renderers/#django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting), and is due to the new way Django renders forms through templates.

Comment: This finally pushed me to figure it out, thanks! The answer is here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/renderers/#django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting

Comment: Feel free to add the link to your answer and I will be happy to accept it rather than creating another answer :)

Comment: thanks, i've done just that!